# Can't delete data from my Firebase database

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, python-3.6

I can read my firebase database and I can push new data to it. I'm using pyrebase and python 3.6. However when it comes to removing data from it I cannot remove any data. Any suggestions?

```
import pyrebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "***",
  "authDomain": "****.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://***.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "*****.appspot.com",
  "serviceAccount": "secret/****.json"
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

auth = firebase.auth()
email = "*****"
password = "****"
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)

db = firebase.database()

charities_d = {
    "haaaaello": {
        "obj": None,
        "open": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "bags": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    },
    "bantdddder": {
        "obj": None,
        "open": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "bags": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    },
    "dsddd": {
        "obj": None,
        "open": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "bags": [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    },
}

# db.child("users").push({"name": "bub"}, user["idToken"])
# db.child("users").child({"name": "bub"}).remove(user["idToken"])
db.child("users").child("bub").remove(user['idToken'])
```

The structure of the database is 
DB:
-users -> bub & anotherName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right I figured out my own question. It's late I guess I've just spent too much time on this one! Basically when using `pyrebase` when you push into the database as the higherlevel block it makes a time generated hash. Whereas if you do 

`db.child(COLLECTION).child(ID_OF_ELEMENT).set(DATA, TOKEN)`

Your higher level block becomes the ID_OF_ELEMENT and so when you

`db.child(COLLECTION).child(ID_OF_ELEMENT).remove(TOKEN)`

It actually finds your item and deletes it from the database.